# Format a dataframe using Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has a format like this

```
Date       Grade    Student
1/1/2015    0.15    Brian
1/1/2015    0.05    Steve
1/1/2015    0.02    Connor
1/2/2015    0.14    Brian
1/2/2015    0.05    Steve
```

.....

Is it possible to reformat the dataframe in such a way in that it now looks like this?

```
Date      Brian   Steve   Connor
1/1/2015   0.15    0.05    0.02
1/2/2015   0.14    0.05     -
```

I am quite familiar with Pandas and aggregating columns together but am unsure how to go about compressing them in this particular way, any help woiuld be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
a = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Student', values='Grade')
```

This returns:

```
Out[5]: 
Student   Brian  Connor  Steve
Date                          
1/1/2015   0.15    0.02   0.05
1/2/2015   0.14     NaN   0.05
```

Comment: lol, I was just about to answer this myself as I had found a perfect example on my ext Google search. You are absolutely correct though. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this simple case you can just use `pivot`.

```
>>> df.pivot('Date', 'Student', 'Grade')
Student   Brian  Connor  Steve
Date                          
1/1/2015   0.15    0.02   0.05
1/2/2015   0.14     NaN   0.05
```